# Creating SVG stacking blocks / divs / legos

Tags: jquery, graphics, graph, svg, block

I have searched and come up with multiple "pseudo solutions" for what I am looking for either by trying to modify jquery bar graphs or mansonary or svg etc, but I thought I would just ask if someone had better solutions for me.  PLEASE.

I need to create a stacking plan that shows tenants in a building by how much space they use per floor can be by size or percentage.  I included a link below of a simple example via jpg.  I need to color coat it by lease expiration and make it dynamic - click on the block and pass id variable.  I just don't think css block float is the easiest to apply but I could be wrong.

[image: Block image]

The example is the best explanation.  I think the lego block question was close.

Comment: I took a rough stab it using JQ Highcharts.
[http://jsfiddle.net/ayJYV/260/](http://jsfiddle.net/ayJYV/260/) for an example.  I would love some recommendations on how to adjust the data series.  I would like to order by suite numbers per floor.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this much simpler with plain HTML? Along the lines of this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .floorName, .suites, .suite {display:inline-block}
      .floorName  {width:100px}
      .suites     {
        width:500px;
        height:100%;
      }
      .suite      {
        position:relative;
        color:white; 
        background-color:#FF9934;
        text-align:center;
        height:100%;
      }
      /* This draws the border around the suites */
      .suite:before {
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        border:1px solid black;
        top:-1px;
        left:-1px;
      }
      .expire2012 {background-color:#3266CC}
      .expire2013 {background-color:#FE0000}
      .expire2014 {background-color:#99CC67}
      .expire2015 {background-color:#00FF01}
      .expire2016 {background-color:#993400}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="floor">
      <div class="floorName">Floor 12</div>
      <div class="suites">
        <div style="width:100%" class="suite expire2012">Suite 1200</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="floor">
      <div class="floorName">Floor 11</div>
      <div class="suites">
        <div style="width:40%" class="suite">Suite 1100</div
        ><div style="width:40%" class="suite">Suite 1110</div
        ><div style="width:20%" class="suite expire">Suite 1120</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="floor">
      <div class="floorName">Floor 10</div>
      <div class="suites">
        <div style="width:100%" class="suite expire2013">Suite 1000</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="floor">
      <div class="floorName">Floor 9</div>
      <div class="suites">
        <div style="width:40%" class="suite expire2016">Suite 900</div
       ><div style="width:60%" class="suite expire2014">Suite 910</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was trying to avoid CSS floats and focus on jQuery.  I think I have it figured out now.  I am going to use a loop to generate the data series and use a horizontal bar chart.  Because the info it dynamic and need to pass variables it will work better using jq chart. http://jsfiddle.net/ayJYV/261/  is the answer I was looking for.  Thanks much for the help though!